# convert int array to byte array in Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to create some random int arrays and write it to a `xyz.txt` file in  Golang.
How to convert `ids` which is an `int` array to `byte` array, as `file.Write` accepts `[]byte` as a parameter. What is the correct way to achieve writing random integer arrays to a text file.

```golang
func main() {
    var id int
    var ids []int
    var count int

    f, err := os.Create("xyz.txt")
    check(err)

    defer f.Close()

    for j := 0; j < 5; j++ {
        count = rand.Intn(100)
        for i := 0; i < product_count; i++ {
            id = rand.Intn(1000)
            ids = append(product_ids, product_id)
        }
        n2, err := f.Write(ids)
        check(err)
        fmt.Printf("wrote %d bytes\n", n2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that depends solely on the format your file should have and has nothing to do with "converting int to byte array". Probably you should fmt.Fprintf to your file.

Comment: But I am getting this error on line `f.Write(ids)` that `argument 1 has incompatible type`. I want to write the ids in a text file. If this is not the correct way. Please tell me the correct manner of doing this.

Comment: Yeah, but a byte array is essentially an array of characters (in byte representation), I think you don't want your ints interpreted as characters but instead want to write the digits that make up the numbers (those are two different things). You should probably use fmt.Fprintf as Volker suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `fmt.Fprint`, as this simplified working sample:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("xyz.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    w := bufio.NewWriter(f)
    defer w.Flush()

    for j := 0; j < 5; j++ {
        count := 4 //count := rand.Intn(100)
        for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
            fmt.Fprint(w, rand.Intn(1000), " ")
        }
        fmt.Fprintln(w)
    }
}
```

`xyz.txt` output file:

```
81 887 847 59 
81 318 425 540 
456 300 694 511 
162 89 728 274 
211 445 237 106
```